# Lifespan of temporary object passed by reference to function

Tags: c++, object-lifetime, temporary-objects

Yes, similar questions have been asked before but they weren't exactly the same (or at least the answers provided weren't sufficient for me).

My general question is: what is the lifespan of a temporary object created while calling a function?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout << "A()" << endl;
    }
    A(const A&)
    {
        cout << "A(const A&)" << endl;
    }
    A(A&&)
    {
        cout << "A(A&&)" << endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        cout << "~A()" << endl;
    }
};

class Container
{
public:
    A& getA()
    {
        return a;
    }

private:
    A a;
};

void f(A & a)
{
    cout << "f()" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    f (Container().getA());
    cout << "main()" << endl;
}
```

This yields output:

```
A()
f()
~A()
main()
```

I create a temporary instance of `Container` and pass a reference to its field to the function `f()`. The output suggests that the instance of `Container` starts life when `f()` is called, lives until the function returns and only then is destroyed. But maybe this output is a fluke.

What does the standard say? Is the reference to `Container::a` valid in the body of `f()`?

Comment: Specifically: _"Temporary objects are destroyed at the end of the full expression they're part of."_.

Comment: @YSC Thanks, I didn't find that question. So that means I can safely use the reference to `Container::a` in `f()`?

Comment: define "safe" ^^ As-is, yes this is safe. But code tend to evolve and the next programmer might not be as cautious as you were asking here. If possible, bind temporaries only to const references.

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise, I meant "is the reference valid (because the object still exists)?".

Comment: Yes, as-is the code is safe: the reference doesn't outlive what it's bound to.